# How to edit the forum form for SPIP 4.2

Tags: forum, spip

In Spip, pages on which a comment can be posted display the form using the `#FORMULAIRE_FORUM` tag. However, I cannot find which file this is linked to. Tt should be the formulaire_forum.html file in the forms folder of the skeleton, but when I modify it, there is no effect. I also tried the file in the root of the "squelettes" folder, to no avail. Can someone provide information on where this file might be hiding?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the forum.html file from the /plugin-dist/forum/forms/ directory and paste it into the /squelettes/forms/ directory.

In this file, you will find all the HTML tags used in the CSS, and you can add the necessary Div or Span to enhance your form.

Once you find the CSS path, simply modify or add the style in the appropriate style sheet (e.g., spip.css, form.css, style.css, ...).